# Column in spark dataset not getting updated using withColumn

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to update the value of a column in a dataset using withColumn, but somehow its not working. I have a dataset of ReconEntity( a case class), it looks like :-

```
case class ReconEntity(rowId: String,
                       groupId: String,
                       amounts: List[Amount],
                       processingDate: Long,
                       attributes: Map[String, String],
                       entityType: String,
                       isDuplicate: String)
```

and the value of isDuplicate is "true" initially. Now on the basis of certain logic, I want to change this "true" to "false". Here's my logic:-

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("rowId").orderBy(desc("processingDate"))
    reconEntities.withColumn("ROW_NUMBER", row_number().over(windowSpec))
      .withColumn("isDuplicate", when(col("ROW_NUMBER") === 1, lit("false")).otherwise(col("isDuplicate")))
      .drop("ROW_NUMBER")
      .as[ReconEntity]
```

reconEntities is Dataset[ReconEntity]. In the above logic, I am grouping all the records with same rowId and ordering them on the basis of processingDate, and adding the numbering to the group having the same rowId. Now for the first row of every group, I am changing the value of isDuplicate to be "false". But its not working when I am running my spark job. Is there anything wrong with my logic?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Could you share some example data?

Comment: On the basis of above logic, for a group having the same rowids, the first row of the group should have the value of isDuplicate as "false".

Comment: Remember that DataFrames are immutable. The withColumn method returns a new DataFrame with the column added/modified. Make sure you are using or storing this new DataFrame appropriately. Your code does not show what you are doing with the new DataFrame. As it is it would not store the new dataframe anywhere

Comment: Hi @mamonu, I am using it like this :-                                                                                     
rawSrcData.map(a => (a._1, flagNonDuplicatesUsingMaxProcessingDate(rawSrcData(a._1)))), the rawSrcData is Map[String, Dataset[ReconEntity]] and flagNonDuplicatesUsingMaxProcessingDate is the function where I am performing the above logic and returning the same and then i am printing the rawSrcData, will it not get updated?

Comment: No, it will not, as noted above. You need to assign the expression to a new variable.

Comment: You were right, after assigning the dataframe to a variable, it worked